# read data from API and save it to csv file on python

Tags: python, python-3.x

**While saving the data that I read from the api on csv format I am not able to export it**

```
import requests
import csv

api_address='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=c813d30c0e935c06d54403f3b77bb104&q='

city = input('City Name :')

url = api_address + city

json_data = requests.get(url).json()

with open('people.csv','w') as csvfile:

    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    for item in  json_data:

       writer.writerow(item)
```

Comment: What is the expected output, while writing you are only looking at first elements.